# An equally quick alternative to SecurityElement.Escape(string) to escape XML special characters?

Tags: .net, xml, string, escaping

I ran across this [`SecurityElement.Escape(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) method to escape special XML characters in a String, however it seems to be oddly placed in the Security namespace considering I'm just using the generic [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) namespace and a basic String of XML, not really security related.

It converts the following special XML characters.

```
< to &lt;
> to &gt;
" to &quot;
' to &apos;
& to &amp;
```

Is there an **equally quick static method call somewhere inside the XML namespace** for escaping these characters, without using higher level classes like XmlReader, XmlDocument, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good summary of the options is in the following:

[Different ways to escape XML](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that there's not a quick option listed in that article residing in the `System.Xml` namespace. The `HttpUtility` class is promising but then I would have to reference in the System.Web.dll assembly just for that logic. If these are the only options then I will likely stick with the `SecurityElement.Escape` method because it's already naturally referenced into programs.

Comment: Agree, we use it most often for the same reason.

Comment: Be aware that some of these methods are outdated or incomplete. For example, you should not use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, but `WebUtility.HtmlEncode`. @JohnK - `WebUtility` resides in the `System.Net` namespace and is .NET Core compatible.